# Vizsla vs. pitbull terrier

Tags: identification

The Humane Society told us our dog was a "pitbull terrier", and a "shepherd mix", on two different papers.  It looks a lot like a vizsla for me, but I know nothing about dogs.  Are there any tell-tale signs I can look for, to make the determination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to your vet hospital and they can send a blood sample off to a lab to do DNA testing, it's relatively cheap (30$ where I'm from) and you'll know for sure.